# Getting "invalidEmail" error when trying to insert an ACL in the Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

When using the V3 Google Calendar API, I am attempting to insert an ACL into a calendar. Here is the request body sent:

```
{"role":"owner","scope":{"type":"user","value":"valid_email_address"}}
```

However I get a 400 response back with the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "calendar",
    "reason": "invalidEmail",
    "message": "Invalid email."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid email."
 }
}
```

The email sent is an RFC compliant email, and I have used the API testing tool to confirm that the API does return a different error message when a truly invalid email value is sent (for instance if the string is just "12345").

Given this, what is the meaning of the error I am getting? Does it have to do with that email possibly not existing anymore within my GSuite domain?

Answer (score 0):

### The correct syntax is not `"<email_address>"` but `"email_address"`.

For example:

`{"role":"owner","scope":{"type":"user","value":"legal@stackoverflow.com"}}`

- Another way to obtain a 400 error is to provide an email that does not correspond the expected pattern.

  E.g. `"value":"legal@stackoverflow."` or `"value":"legal@stackoverflow"`.
- Typing mistakes like `"value":"lega@stackoverflo.com"` will not be noticed by the API, neither will it verify either the email you provided still exists in your GSuite Domain.

Comment: The value is actually as you pointed out. There are no actual greater than / less than symbols in my real value.

Comment: Do you experience the same error wiht other email addresses? Can you see any pattern?

Comment: No pattern that I can see, I've tried simple ones to complex ones.

Comment: Does the error only occur when coding or also when testing with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert)?